# IPTC .NET read/write c# library

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, jpeg, iptc

I am looking for some library to read/write IPTC metadata from Jpg files. 
Open source or paid, doesn't matter.

It should work with .NET 3.5 and c#.

Does anybody know such a library? I googled but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace wictest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stream = new FileStream("1.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
            var metadata = decoder.Frames[0].Metadata as BitmapMetadata;
            if(metadata != null)
                Console.WriteLine(metadata.Keywords.Aggregate((old, val) => old + "; " + val));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to reference *PresentationCore.dll* and *WindowsBase.dll* to get access to the System.Windows.Media namespace.