# Write ITPC metadata into image

Tags: c#, image, metadata, iptc

I have to modify the iptc metadata of 6000+ jpg images. Unfortunately, I didn't found any library or even an example for doing so.

Could you please give me a hint how to modify the metadata of images or point me to a site where I can inform myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IPTC .NET read/write c# library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597079/iptc-net-read-write-c-sharp-library)

Comment: I already read this question & answer, but as I understand it, the code only describes how to read metadata, not how to write it

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance at the [System.Windows.Media.Imaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.aspx) namespace revealed the [`InPlaceBitmapMetadaWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.inplacebitmapmetadatawriter.aspx) class. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Stream pngStream = new System.IO.FileStream("smiley.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
PngBitmapDecoder pngDecoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(pngStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapFrame pngFrame = pngDecoder.Frames[0];
InPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter pngInplace = pngFrame.CreateInPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter();
if (pngInplace.TrySave() == true)
{
    pngInplace.SetQuery("/Text/Description", "Have a nice day."); 
}

pngStream.Close();
```

Comment: I'll have a look at it tomorrow. Thank you!