# Embedded file in jpeg

Tags: jpeg

I'm searching an easy way to have a file embedded in a jpeg. I'm not trying to hide anything inside but I want to have a the additional information as jpeg "built-in", so I don't need to encrypt anything. I found the EXIF interface but there isn't a tag "additional file", I can add only some metadata like date and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just create an archive (e.g. a 7z file) and append the archive file to the end of the jpeg using copy

```
copy /b image.jpg + data.7z image_with_data.jpg
```

Alternatively you could embed the information as [IPTC data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597079/iptc-net-read-write-c-sharp-library)

See

- [How to Embed in JPEG](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/embed-jpeg-43989.html)
- [Hide files inside of JPEG images](http://lifehacker.com/282119/hide-files-inside-of-jpeg-images)

Comment: Since I have to do it via code, I think I can write at the end of the file in append mode and to save at the end with some signature the original size to have back the additional file. Thanks!!